# What the operator `<--` do in C?

Tags: c, numbers, operators

I am very new to programming. I know about numerical and logical operators. But I have never seen this- `<--` operator. I searched over internet but got nothing helpful.

Here is the code:

```
int i=5;
while(0 <-- i){
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

The output is:

```
 4
 3
 2
 1
```

What is this operator? What does it do?

---

Edit: I also wish to know about other confusing *composite operators* like this.

Comment: It is challenging to search for, but see this answer, it's helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<--` is not an operator, it is `<` and `--` written without space. Just to make it clear, I rewrite the code like this-

```
while(0 < --i)
```

First the value of `i` is decreased, and then compared if it is greater than `0`.

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator).